# Behavior of e.preventDefault();

Tags: jquery

I am learning *jQuery* and am looking to clarify what `e.preventDefault()` does. From what I have read it prevents the default behaviour of the event.

An example in my case would be that I have an anchor tag which rather than take me to a new page I want it to display a modal on my screen. So my *jQuery* looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#boxShow').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#light").fadeIn();
    $('#fade').fadeIn();
});
```

Is the `preventDefault()` enabling me to perform a different event?

Apologies if this is a stupid question

Comment: If #boxShow is an anchor tag, preventDefault will prevent page transition, and let you do all the effect as defined.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your answers, makes total sense now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy, it prevents the **default event** from happening. For example an `<a>` element normally opens a link on click. In order to override that you will need to use this function.

This is easier to read once you use `event` instead of the acronym `e`.

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: lol you got to know your parameters to understand it ofcourse :p here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/rUNtx/1/) ;)

Comment: +1, nice hint on renaming 'e' to 'event' to help making this easier to understand. @Richardlewis: checkout the jQuery documentation on this http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ The online documentation in general is full of good and usefull information as well as plenty of examples to explain the methods and parameters.

Answer (score 2):

With an anchor element, the "default event" is to read the `href` (*hypertext reference*) value, and form a HTTP Request to for this location. In short, it directs the user to the URL of `href` value.

Therefore `preventDefault()` will prevent the `href` property from calling a HTTP Request, and just run your code underneath. I.e. the 2 `fadeIn()` methods.

Comment: This is a bad explaination. `e.preventDefault()` is also used with a form submit button for example. And there are lots of other elements that have a default event bound to them, which you can prevent.

Comment: @Sem I don't see how this is a bad explanation. The OP has used an anchor element as there example, and I've explained how it works with that example..

Comment: He is asking about what `e.preventDefault()` does. Not what it does in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

As per [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), `e.preventDefault();` prevents the default action of the event to be triggered.

In case of an anchor/hyperlink for example it should prevent the link from redirecting to the specified location.

Answer (score 1):

From the [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) site:

> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be
>   triggered.

So in the case of the anchor tag, it'll not take the user to another url, leaving you open to do what you want in the click event.

p.s it's not a stupid question :-)

Answer (score 0):

`e.preventDefault();` will prevent default behavior of the action 
   in case  anchor(a) it will prevent opening new url associated with anchor.
   in case of form it will prevent submitting of form.
  but e.preventDefault(); would not work in IE as I dont support it. You shoould use `e.returnValue = false;`

code:

```
if(e.preventDefault){
      e.preventDefault();

}
else{
    e.returnValue = false; 
}
```